# Comando tr linux presenta comportamiento extraño con ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú

Tags: linux, bash, tildes, tr

Cuando escribo esto en mi consola de linux, la cual tengo instalada en windows 10:

```
echo ñ | tr 'ñ' 'n'
```

Me da este resultado:

```
nn
```

Me pasa algo similar con esto:

```
echo áéíóú | tr 'áéíóú' 'aeiou'
```

Resultado:

```
ueuouuuuuu
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a saber por qué pasa esto y como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr` no funciona en UTF-8. Es un programa muy simple. Reemplaza un byte con otro byte, no un carácter con otro carácter. Caracteres pueden ser más largos que un byte. Por ejemplo, `ñ` está representado en UTF-8 con dos bytes, `0xc3 0xb1`. `tr` reemplaza los dos con `n`.

Si quieres eliminar acentos, un buen comando es

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

Por ejemplo

```
$ echo Éste que veis aquí, de rostro aguileño, de cabello castaño \
    | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
Este que veis aqui, de rostro aguileno, de cabello castano
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, encontré algo similar con este comando:
echo áéíóúñaeiou | sed -e 'y/áéíóúñ/aeioun/'
Pero me parece que el tuyo es más util ya que traduce todo el utf-8 por ascii, según lo entiendo. Así que esta genial. Mil gracias

Comment: @CarlosMilton sed funciona, pero con sed es fácil olvidar algo, por ejemplo letras mayúsculas o `¿¡ü` ;)

Answer (score 2):

esto se produce tal vez porque la consola WSL `Subsystem-Linux` tiene como predeterminado el formato `En_US_ISO-8859-1` o `ISO-8859-1` `por lo tanto no visualizaras los caracteres.

Hay que tener en cuenta, que la consola de Linux, trabaja a un formato, los entornos gráficos a otro formato, y los editores de texto/IDE's puedes definir para cada archivo el formato. Esto quiere decir que si coinciden los formatos tendrás problemas.

Podrias probar una opción que sería comprobar el `locale`

```
$ sudo locale -a

C
en_US.utf8
es_ES.utf8
POSIX
```

Si no lo tienes de esta manera podrías reconfigurar el locale con el formato UTF-8 para que puedas visualiar los caracteres especiales en español como la `ñ` de esta manera

```
#sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

y seleccionas esta opción
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si luego de hacer eso te sigue apareciendo el mismo problema podrías hacer un escape y solo visualizando la primera línea del reemplazo es decir de esta manera:

```
echo ñ | tr 'ñ' 'n\n' | head -n 1
```

`Output: n`

Comment: Esto no resuelve nada.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me parece que la primera opción quizá implica demasiado, para lo que quiero realizar solo con un archivo, y la segunda me sirve solo para una letra. Muchas gracias de todas maneras ;)